# How to increase N from 10 random points and up to 10^8 points in Monte Carlo

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is Monte Carlo integration

I want to make n increases like 10, 10^2, 10^3 till 10^9, instead of making n is constant like I did in my code
I tried with do loop to make n but when I start to print, I don't get 10,10**2 till 10**9
as I want to print this n like in the output

```
 subroutine monte(a,b,integration,answer,error)
 real,external::f
 real::a,b,p,summ,x
 real,intent(out) :: integration,answer,error
 integer::n,i,j
 n=10000
 summ=0
 do i=1,n
     call random_number(x)
     x=a+x*(b-a)
     summ=summ+f(x)
 enddo
     integration=(b-a)*summ/n
     answer=(2*b**3/3-3*b**2/2)-(2*a**3/3-3*a**2/2) !Manual calculation for the integeral
     error=abs(answer-integration)*100/answer
     print*,n,integration,answer,error
 end subroutine
 
 real function f(x)
 real :: x
 f=(2*x**2-3*x)
 end
```

```
 output

   n             integeration 
   10            46.0789
   10**2         46.098
   10**3         46.96
   |
   |
   10**9         46.96
```

Comment: Although you do not mention the values for `a` and `b`, I suspect that you do not want to compute `answer` in the manner that you have.  The subtraction of large nearly equal entities often suffers from catastrophic cancellation.  It would be better to factor the terms,  `anwer = 2*b**2*(b/3 - 0.75) - 2*a**2*(a/3-0.75)`.  Note, `0.75` should be declared with a kind type parameter suffix.

Comment: a = 2 , b= 5
but my question is about n, I want increase n not only use 10000 like l wrote in my code

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Could you not make `n` an input parameter to your subroutine `monte` and loop over different `n=10^i, i=1,9`?

Comment: I can read.  I know what your question is.  I know how one could achieve want you want.  Have you thought about passing `n` into the subroutine as an argument?  Have you thought about a nested do-loop where `n` is set in the outer loop?

Comment: Yes, thanks I was doing like you said, but I was making the do loop generally so if effect on my integration, but Now I did it right,
And sorry #evets I just repeat the question. I don't mean anything

Comment: In a previous question (now linked) you had such a mechanism which involved powers of 2.  Powers of ten would be no different as a concept.

Comment: You also use exactly that mechanism in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469980/how-can-i-make-the-difference-between-a-result-and-the-preceding-one-in-do-loops